# microsoft grap API: how to access an excel file on a different site and perform edits

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to edit an excel file using Microsoft graph API but I'm not entirely sure how to maneuver my way with Microsoft graph.

I know I would like grab a hold of that file's ID but I'm not sure how to get the files of a different site.

What I'm trying to do is list all the sites, get ID of my target site, list files of that target site, then get ID of the excel file. Sorry I'm just too overwhelmed at the moment to identify which endpoints I need to use.

I tried to perform this first in python by using packages such as O365 and some other ms graph wrapper packages but they either are incomplete or the documentation is not too good.

If you could point me to the correct endpoints that I need to use, it would really help me a lot.

Comment: You can try getting all the sites in your tenant using the call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*` and you can pick the id for a site and if you have the file in a document library you can use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/drives/{Document library id}/root/children`. Give a try and let me know if it helped.

Comment: To get document library id or drives use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/drives`

Comment: thank you for your help @Shiva-MSFTIdentity. I will give it a try.

Comment: hi @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I just have a follow up question. I am now able to get the file ID of the excel file that I would like to modify. and now I guess I need to make a session with it right? the endpoint that I can find is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{drive-item-id}/workbook/createSession. but this seems only applicable if the file is on my drive but the file is on a different one.

Comment: You can use it on sharepoint files as well :)- Please see my answer below

Comment: Hi niccolo, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try getting all the sites in your tenant using the call below.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

and you can pick the id for a site and if you have the file in a document library you can use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/drives/{Document library id}/root/children
```

You can create session for workbook not only on onedrive but also on sharepoint by giving the right path.

As you have the file id you can use below call to create session.

```
{Path where the file is stored}/Items/{file id}/workbook/createSession
```

Request body:

```
{
  "persistChanges": true
}
```

Comment: thanks Shiva. do you have a reference link for this endpoint? {Path where the file is stored}/Items/{file id}/workbook/createSession. I'm trying to use this but I'm not sure what is the exact syntax and also the what the payload should contain when submitting this request

Comment: I am currently trying in postman and I am getting an error: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217. even though Im sending the correct access token.

Comment: I already have the site ID and the file ID, also the doc library ID but I'm just not sure of the APIs syntax

Comment: Here is the http call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/soaadteam.sharepoint.com,c1178396-d845-46fa-bc0c-453d2951dad5,19ee9a1e-001d-48f1-9ee8-b0adfde54e45/drives/b!loMXwUXY-ka8DEU9KVHa1R6a7hkdAPFInuiwrf3lTkWmzNPKD2ILQLNdmX03mXTy/Items/01LPJ34YRUWMRB2O2NWNCJM2RYIOAMGKUG/workbook/createSession` and give the request body as above which I mentioned `{"persistChanges": true}` by selecting the JSON in body in POSTMAN. CompactToken error is a token issue which is not proper. Please use Graph Explorer and give it a try to rectify token issue.

Comment: thanks for all your help Shiva I'm now able to get the excel file and I also  tried to add a new sheet. 1 item though, when I test it in ms graphs, it says it cannot find the file that I'm working on but when I try on Postman, it does execute it as expected.